# Prestashop 1.7.6 wishlist dimmed page when adding item and cannot click

Tags: prestashop-1.7

I'm using Prestashop 1.7.6 with a third party theme.
I'd like to have my customers to use the wishlist feature.
I have no issue on enabling it and I can see the add to wishlist button on the products.
But when I click that button to add a product to the wishlist, a dimmed page appear with a popup that ask to select on which wishlist to add the product to, but I cannot click anywhere:[Issue with wishlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ju0G7.png)
All you can do is scroll the background site up&down and only a refresh of the page is needed to return to the product page.
Looks like a layer between the mouse click and the wishlist popup that does not allow any action.

Any idea?
I tried removing, installing the wishlist module and also tried a third party one from ets-soft without any success...

Thank you for your time.
PS: website is https://www.immaginelab.com/shop

I tried removing the wishlist module, re-installing it and tried a third party one without any success... same behaviour happens.

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you are using the [latest version](https://github.com/PrestaShop/blockwishlist/releases/tag/v3.0.0) of the blockwishlist module.

If it does not solve the issue, probably your theme is overriding some module template file in a wrong way that needs to be adjusted.

I would therefore check /themes/[youtheme]/modules/blockwishlist folder for overriden TPL(s) and compare them with original modules one.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply!
I'm using another module for wishlists (same features but from ets-soft).... but the same issues happens with the latest version of the original one.
I bet my third party theme is overriding something, but what do I have to check under that path in side the TPL files?
Thanks!

Comment: EDIT: I've checked inside that theme folder but the ets-soft wishlist module is not there... instead is into /modules/ets_wishlist_pres17